# Restrict Text Box to Pattern and validate Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, regex, validation

I'm trying to set up a text box to restrict to a format for a New Zealand Drivers Licence, so I've been looking in to regex to validate this, but I'm not actually sure how to do it.

The field needs to be restricted to 2 letters followed by 6 numbers (AA123456)

So far I've come up with this pattern `/([A-Za-z]{2}\d{4})/` which I got from http://www.regexr.com/, but after looking around for how to use regex in the input field I can't work it out. I'm wanting it to validate as they type, so say they type `AAB` it won't add the `B`.

My code so far:

```
$("#licenceNo").keyup(function() {
    var data = $("#licenceNo").val().match(/([A-Za-z]{2}\d{6})/);
}
```

But I'm not sure what to do next...

I also want to validate this server side using PHP. Do I just use the same expression?

Can anyone post links to tutorials? All I can find when I search is EDU papers.

Comment: Use input mask; if your pages are HTML5

Comment: @hjpotter92 link to it? I Googled input mask and just got Microsoft pages :). Is it a plugin?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A client side approach probably makes more sense than doing server side validation. I can't think of why you'd need to do this in PHP.

This approach will let you remove the last character if it doesn't match your pattern and set the textbox to red. Otherwise, it will be set it to green and let you continue typing.

```
$("#licenseNo").on("change keyup", function() {
    isValid = isValidLicenseNo(this.value);
    if (isValid) {
        $(this).css( "background-color", "green" );
    } else {
        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0,-1));
        $(this).css( "background-color", "red" );
    }
});
function isValidLicenseNo(text) {
    if(text.length < 2) return text.match(/(^[A-Za-z]{0,1})$/);
    return text.match(/(^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{0,6}$)/);
}
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckirksey3/C5WxK/811/)

I had to make some modification to your RegEx. The '^' and '$' anchors prevent the user from adding characters indefinitely after the initial match. The range after your decimal match ('\d{0,6}') helps license plates match while the user is still typing them out. It was tricky to get a RegEx that correctly matched for the 0-1 character case so I cheated on that and wrote a separate RegEx.

Comment: Thanks! The only reason I check server side is in case someone has Javascript disabled on their browser which some of our clients do :)