# How to executing a validation in text box number format like 44.44

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I want to Check the value to both javascript and php ,which one should be like this format 22.22 or 00.44 or 44 or 55.00.

I have the below code.

```
$(function(){

    // $('.pixcel_rate').keypress(function (event) {
    //         return isNumber(event, this)
    // });
   $('.pixcel_rate').keypress(function (event) {
            return validateFloatKeyPress($(this).val());
    });
  });


// THE SCRIPT THAT CHECKS IF THE KEY PRESSED IS A NUMERIC OR DECIMAL VALUE.  


function validateFloatKeyPress(evt,el) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    var number = el.value.split('.');

    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    //just one dot (thanks ddlab)
    if(number.length>1 && charCode == 46){
         return false; 
    }
    //get the carat position
    var caratPos = getSelectionStart(el);
    var dotPos = el.value.indexOf(".");

    console.log(caratPos);
    console.log(dotPos);
    if( caratPos >1  && dotPos>-1 && (number[0].length > 1)){
        return false;
    }
    if( caratPos > dotPos && dotPos>-1 && (number[1].length > 1)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function getSelectionStart(o) {
    if (o.createTextRange) {
        var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate()
        r.moveEnd('character', o.value.length)
        if (r.text == '') return o.value.length
        return o.value.lastIndexOf(r.text)
    } else return o.selectionStart
}
```

Comment: i think maybe you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150179/restrict-text-box-to-pattern-and-validate-jquery-and-php

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here. Are you looking for the format "XX.XX"? where X is any digit? e.g. "00.44" is ok, "44.00" is ok, but "44" fails?

Comment: @chatnoir as I read it, 44 is correct.

Comment: Did you intentionally use the same digit twice? or it can be 12.31 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_match in php to see if it matches the pattern.

```
preg_match("/^\d{2}\.\d{2}$|^\d{2}$/", $val);
```

This matches either two digits, dot, two digits. Or just two digits.

Example test cases:
https://3v4l.org/G6D8l

Comment: You might shorten it to `^\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?$` without the alternation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to achieve this. Below is the regex for your requirement.
https://regex101.com/r/N5gbqs/3/

```
function validateFloatKeyPress(value) {
    //returns null if it doesnt match the given regular expression
    return value.toString().match(/^(\d{2}|\d{2}\.\d{2})$/)
}

function validateFloatKeyPress(value) {
    //returns false if it doesnt match the given regular expression
    return (/^(\d{2}|\d{2}\.\d{2})$/).test(value.toString())
}
```

Comment: The value was checked correctly.But it not working when the event being action on keyup or keypress.it doesn't allowed to type more than one character of number